# getting Syslog Events in Java

Tags: java, debian, syslog

I have a Java application which should watch for some Syslogevents (Xenstore dismount). So the question is, how to do it in a very fast way (If the event occurs I've not much time to react).

Is there an quick way to do it? Or is the native way in permanently reading the file not so bad as I found it.

I'm using Debian and Java 1.6 which is not changable for me.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, a clean and efficient way to be notified of filesystem events ([`WatchService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/WatchService.html)) was introduced only in Java 7.

If you cannot use that, the best way is probably to use [`ProcessBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) to invoke `tail -f` on the logfile and read from the process's STDOUT in an endless loop, which will block whenever there are no events.